# iOS iFrame in UIWebView Uses basic authentication but no popup shows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview, basic-authentication

Our app has a `UIWebView` with an iFrame inside it, and the website the iframe points to requires basic authentication.

In a browser the alert popup displays and allows us to log in, however in the `UIWebView` it does not.

Is there a setting or something we've missed?

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the official Developer forums and as for now, `UIWebView` does not support authentication challenges in iOS. Please read here (requires developer account): [UIWebView does not directly support authentication challenges](https://devforums.apple.com/message/904426#904426.)

A workaround is to load the html in `NSURLConnection` (or `NSURLSession`), execute the authentication challenge and then assign the data the web view.

That won't work in all scenarios, though.

Comment: Also note that authenticating a user via webview means high chance of getting your app rejected.http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/32520-my-ios-app-was-rejected-by-apple-not-allow-login-in-web-view/

Answer (score 0):

Some time iFrame URL try to load from the cache.
Try to set the response header  `Cache-Control:no-cache`.
401 Authorization requests will be blocked because of the  cross-origin request